# ¿Cómo puedo incluir en mi login (hecho con JSP) el validar y entrar por perfil de usuario?

Tags: java, web, jsp

Cordial saludo

¿Cómo puedo cambiar el perfil de usuario en mi login? Actualmente lo tengo de la siguiente manera y solo me entra a la página administrador, estoy usando JSP y Servlet. El código en mi controlador sería:

```
UsuariosDao dao = new UsuariosDao();
    Usuarios user = new Usuarios();
    int r=0;
   
 protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request,
 HttpServletResponse response)
             throws ServletException, IOException {
         response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
           
             String accion=request.getParameter("accion");
             if(accion.equals("ingresar"))
             {
             
             String usuario =request.getParameter("email");
             //String nombrecompleto =request.getParameter(dao.getUsuarios("name"));
             String pass = request.getParameter("password");
            
             user.setCorreo(usuario);
             
             
             user.setPassword(pass);
             r=dao.validarUsuario(user);
             if(r==1){
                  request.getSession().setAttribute("usuario", usuario);
                  //request.getSession().setAttribute("nom", nombrecompleto);
                   //request.getSession().setAttribute("usuario",nombre);
                  response.sendRedirect("administrador/index.jsp");
                 //request.getRequestDispatcher("administrador/index.jsp").forward(request,
 response);
             }else{
                  response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
                 //request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp").forward(request,
 response);
             }
             
             }else{
                 response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
                  //request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp").forward(request,
 response);
             }
       
     }
```

El código en mi clase `usuarioDao` es el siguiente

```
 public int validarUsuario(Usuarios users) {
          int r=0;
          String sql="select * from usuarios where Mail_users=? and Pass_users=?";
        try
        {
            conn=cn.getConexion();
            ps =conn.prepareStatement(sql);
           
            ps.setString(1, users.correo);
            ps.setString(2, users.password);
            
            rs=ps.executeQuery();
            while(rs.next()){
                r=r+1;
                users.setCorreo(rs.getString("Mail_users"));
                users.setPassword(rs.getString("Pass_users"));
               
                
            }
            if(r==1)
            {
                return 1;
            }else{
                return 0;
            }
        }catch(SQLException e){return 0;}
     }
```

En mi base de datos tengo una columna con el nombre perfil 1,2,3 si es 1=administrador, si 2=docente. Agradezco su colaboración.

Controlador

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
throws ServletException, IOException {
  response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
  PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
  String accion = request.getParameter("accion");
  if (accion.equals("ingresar")) {

    String usuario = request.getParameter("email");
    //String nombrecompleto =request.getParameter(dao.getUsuarios("name"));
    String pass = request.getParameter("password");

    user.setCorreo(usuario);


    user.setPassword(pass);
    r = dao.validarUsuario(user);
    if (r == 1) {
      HttpSession session = request.getSession();
      session.setAttribute("usuario", user);
      //HttpSession usua =request.getSession(true);
      //usua.setAttribute("usuario",user);
      //request.getSession().setAttribute("nom", nombrecompleto);
      //request.getSession().setAttribute("usuario",nombre);
      response.sendRedirect("administrador/index.jsp");
      //request.getRequestDispatcher("administrador/index.jsp").forward(request, response);
    } else {
      response.sendRedirect("index.jsp?accion=usuario&claveincorrecta");
      //out.println("<div class='text-danger text-center'>Usuario y/o Clave incorrecta!</div>");
      //request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }

  } else {
    response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
    //request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp").forward(request, response);
  }

}
```

anexo tengo un java interface donde hago la validacion

> public interface validar {    public int validarUsuario(Usuarios
> users);  }

como puedo modificar este codigo utilizando lo que ya tengo para poder iniciar sesión usando el perfil de usuario en mi base de datos tengo un campo de tipo Interger con el nombre Type_users si 1 = administrador , 2 = docente y 3 = tutor
Gracias por su tiempo

Answer (score 0):

Siempre entra como administrador porque en el while tienes este código:
r=r+1;
Entonces si encuentras un usuario y el código entra al while, le sumas valor 1 a la variable r.

Lo que deberías hacer es obtener el usuario de la base de datos incluyendo el tipo de usuario.

y en el sendRedirect rediriges según el tipo de usuario.

ejemplo:

```
 public Usuarios validarUsuario(Usuarios users) {
      Usuarios user = null;
      int r=0;
      String sql="select nombre_usuario, pass_usuario, tipo_usuario  
                     from usuarios where Mail_users=? and 
                     Pass_users=?";
    try {

        conn = cn.getConexion();
        ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
       
        ps.setString(1, users.correo);
        ps.setString(2, users.password);
        
        
        rs = ps.executeQuery();
        if (rs.next()){
            user = new Users();
            users.setCorreo(rs.getString("Mail_users"));
            users.setPassword(rs.getString("Pass_users"));
            users.setTipo(rs.getString("tipo_usuario "));
        }
        
    }catch(SQLException e){
       user = null; 
    }
        return user;
    }
```

Comment: buenas tardes gracias por tu colaboración , pregunta como quedaria en el controlador , arriba anexe el codigo de mi controlador , gracias por su tiempo

Answer (score 0):

Asumo que tu consulta la tienes bien y que al buscar un usuario, obtienes el tipo de usuario también.

Tu controlador debería ser algo parecido a esto. Saludos

```
String accion = request.getParameter("accion");

if (accion.equals("ingresar")) {
    user.setCorreo(usuario);
    user.setPassword(pass);
        
    r = dao.validarUsuario(user);

    if (r != null) {
        request.getSession().setAttribute("usuario", usuario);

        switch (r.getTipo()) { // aqui evaluas que tipo de usuario que devolvió la 
                                  consulta SQL
            case "1":
                response.sendRedirect("administrador/index.jsp");
                break;
            case "2":
                //rediriges a la pagina tipo 2 
                break;
            case "3":
                //rediriges a la pagina tipo 3;
                break;
        }

    } else {
        response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
    }

 } else {
    response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
 }
```